# Get four numbers random in a array

Tags: arrays, random

I have a array

```
   String[] arr={"a","b","c","d","e","f","a","d","m","e"};
```

I want to get random 4 different numbers from this array.
How must I do?

Comment: 1.) what language is this, please re-tag your question accordingly.

Comment: 2.) How do you want to get numbers out of an array that contains... *strings?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> shuffled = Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
List<String> fourRandoms = shuffled.subList(0, 4);
```

Or, if you want to leave the array untouched:

```
List<String> shuffled = Collections.shuffle(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr)));
List<String> fourRandoms = shuffled.subList(0, 4);
```

EDIT: to remove duplicates from the array, use a Set:

```
Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
List<String> shuffled = Collections.shuffle(new ArrayList<String>(uniqueValues));
List<String> fourRandoms = shuffled.subList(0, 4);
```

Learn the standard Java collections, and avoid using arrays completely. You should use a Set from the beginning if duplicates are not allowed.

Comment: I want to get four numbers randoms and all of them is not same. As your way,only get 4 numbers random of arrays.